# Get data from adyen

Tags: php, laravel-5, fetch-api, adyen

How do we get liability shift, fraud score from adyen API which is integrate into laravel 5.4 as SDK?

```
try {
    $adyen = new AdyenClient();
    $params = array(
        'merchantAccount' => 'MozillionLimitedMP',
        'originalReference' => $order->transcation_id // Replace with the actual PSP reference
    );

    $paymentResult = $adyen->service->getPaymentResult($params);
    $liabilityShift = $paymentResult['paymentResult']['liabilityShift'];
    $fraudScore = $paymentResult['paymentResult']['fraudResult']['score'];

    // Process the liability shift and fraud score accordingly
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd($e);
    // Handle the error
    $bankAccountStatus = ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
}
```

Comment: Laravel 5.4 is about 6 years old - I suggest upgrading to a more recent/secure version

Answer (score 1):

There is no endpoint for getting the outcome of a payment. Instead Adyen sends a webhook which tells you the necessary information. You should basically follow the instructions [here](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/?platform=Web&tab=php_3), there are also PHP code snippets provided.
If you want syncronous responsed in addition to the webhook you should start [here](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/additional-use-cases/advanced-flow-integration/?platform=Web&integration=Drop-in&version=5.51.0)
By default Adyen does not give you the fraud score and liability shift. However you can configure the fields which you receive in your Adyen Customer Area under Developers > Additional data.

If this does not help you probably should reach out to Adyen support directly.

Last but not least: Consider updating to an up to date Laravel version!